# Play framework vs SocketIO how to integrate them?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, socket.io

So we want a Play! application which can communicate with a SocketIO (javascript) client.

What I've tried so far:

Using a Play! build in WebSocket and send an exactly same string as the node.js server did. The result is simply not working. I can see in the chrome frame tab the returning message, but while the message from the nodejs server triggers the onEvent handler, the java implementation never does that.

Using/porting the [socket.io.play](https://github.com/milliondreams/socket.io.play) project. The result was the same as the Play! websocket version, the server gets the message, responds, but the message doesn't trigger the javascript eventhandler.

The third java implementation is the [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio). I haven't tried it yet, but the main concept is problematic when I need to start it on another port instead of using the server port and the build in routing.

Java and scala versions are both welcomed, I can use both.

So my questions:

- Is there any working Play (>=2.3.0) application with SocketIO (>=v1.0)?
- What could be a problem in the build-in WebSocket implementation of the Play! ? How can I use it for the SocketIO protocol?
- Can I take a netty based webapp inside my Play! application without using a new routing mechanism or new ports?
- Is there ANY reference implementation with a more typed or formal language then javascript?

Play Java controller return type example:

```
public class WebSocketWithCallBack extends WebSocket<String> {
    private static List<Out<String>> globalOutList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onReady(In<String> in, final Out<String> out) {
        //Adding the output to the room
        globalOutList.add(out);
        System.out.println("adding output, " + globalOutList.size());
        // For each event received on the socket,
        in.onMessage(new F.Callback<String>() {
            public void invoke(String event) {
                //send event to all outputs
                System.out.println("recieved message: ");
                System.out.println(event);
                for(Out<String> outlocal : globalOutList) {
                    outlocal.write("42[\"chat message\",\"asd\"]");
                }
            }
        });
        // When the socket is closed.
        in.onClose(new F.Callback0() {
            public void invoke() {
                //removing the output when closed
                globalOutList.remove(out);
                System.out.println("removing output, " + globalOutList.size());
            }
        });
    }
}
```